# php sending email

Tags: php

mailer.php

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

$to = "abc@gmail.com";
$subject = "Contact via website";
$name_field = $_POST['name'];
$email_field = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

$body = "From: $name_field\n E-Mail: $email_field\n Message:\n $message";

echo "1";
echo "Data has been submitted to $to!";
mail($to, $subject, $body);

} else {
echo "0";
}
?>
```

jquery code

```
$('.submit').click(function(){
            $('span.msg').css({'visibility': 'visible'}).text('Sending...');
            $.post("mailer.php", $(".contactPage").serialize(),
                function(data){
                    $('span.msg').text((data == "1") ? 'Your Message has been received. Thank you' : "Could not send your message at this time").show();
                });

            return false;    
        });
```

I am always getting

```
Could not send your message at this time
```

I have almost no knowledge in php, whats i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your php script never prints just `1` it prints `0` or `1Data has been submitted to...` thus `(data == "1")` can never be true.

---

btw: Your script could at least use the return value of `mail()` to decide whether it signals success or failure.

Comment: I would suggest that you print {success:true} instead of 1 or 0 .

In the Jquery use a JSON library or simply use (not recommended though) 

function(data){ response=eval(data); if(response.success){ alert("Msg sent"); } }

Answer (score 0):

First of all, check server's mail settings. If your script resides on a server, which you don't administer, the simplest way is to do this is creating a simple PHP file with the following content:

```
<?php 
  mail("youraccount@example.com","test","works"); <br>
?>
```

Run it and check your e-mail.